# Why is "forEach not a function" for this object?

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

This is probably something really dumb, but I don't understand why this doesn't work.

```
var a = {"cat":"large"};

a.forEach(function(value, key, map){
    console.log(value);
});
```

**Uncaught TypeError: a.forEach is not a function**

http://jsfiddle.net/ty7z6pse/

Comment: `forEach` is defined in `Array`'s `prototype`, not on `Object`.

Comment: Because objects don't have `forEach`, arrays do

Comment: do Maps not have this function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Is `var a = {};` not creating a Map?  Why does an array get constructed with `[]` (since `forEach` works on a variable created like that) ?

Comment: @haventchecked No, a `Map` is a new ES6 standard. What you have is an `object literal`. If you want a `Map` instead, it's `var map = new Map(); map.set("cat", "large");`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Object does not have `forEach`, it belongs [to `Array` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). If you want to iterate through each key-value pair in the object and take the values. You can do this:

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(function (key){
    console.log(a[key]);
});
```

**Usage note**: For an object `v = {"cat":"large", "dog": "small", "bird": "tiny"};`, `Object.keys(v)` gives you an array of the keys so you get *["cat","dog","bird"]*

Comment: What do you mean @RGraham?

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to access the result from

`Object.keys(a).forEach(function (key){
    console.log(a[key]);
});`

it was plain text result with no key-value pairs 
Here is an example

```
var fruits = {
    apple: "fruits/apple.png",
    banana: "fruits/banana.png",
    watermelon: "watermelon.jpg",
    grapes: "grapes.png",
    orange: "orange.jpg"
}
```

Now i want to get all links in a separated array , but with this code

```
    function linksOfPics(obJect){
Object.keys(obJect).forEach(function(x){
    console.log('\"'+obJect[x]+'\"');
});
}
```

the result of :

```
linksOfPics(fruits)



"fruits/apple.png"
 "fruits/banana.png"
 "watermelon.jpg"
 "grapes.png"
 "orange.jpg"
undefined
```

I figured out this one which solves what I'm looking for

```
  console.log(Object.values(fruits));
["fruits/apple.png", "fruits/banana.png", "watermelon.jpg", "grapes.png", "orange.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a secure foreach interface to iterate an object and make it reusable and clean with a npm module, then use this,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreach-object

Ex:

```
import each from 'foreach-object';
   
const object = {
   firstName: 'Arosha',
   lastName: 'Sum',
   country: 'Australia'
};
   
each(object, (value, key, object) => {
   console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
   
// Console log output will be:
//      firstName: Arosha
//      lastName: Sum
//      country: Australia
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you are using string , consider that its a json obj

string_var.json()   or JSON.parse(string_var)  , now its usable in foreach