# Why do I get a message saying forEach is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In typescript I defined:

```
class SubjectService implements ISubjectService {

    subject: any;
    subjectId: number = 0;
    subjects = {
        "1": { "id": 1, "name": "Java" },
        "100": { "id": 100, "name": "Test" }
    };

    static $inject = [
        "$http",
        "appConstant",
    ];

    constructor(
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public ac: IAppConstant
        ) {
    }

}
```

I then in my constructor have this code:

```
class SubjectController {

    static $inject = [
        "$scope",
        "subjectService"
    ];

    constructor(
        public $scope,
        public su: ISubjectService
        ) {
        $scope.su = su;

        $scope.rowClicked = (subject, $index) => {
            var self = this;
            if (subject.current && subject.current == true) {
                return;
            }
            su.subjects.forEach(function (subject) {
                subject.current = false;
            });
            su.subject = subject;
            su.subject.current = true;
        }

    }

}
```

But when this runs I am getting a message saying:

TypeError: su.subjects.forEach is not a function
    at Scope.SubjectController.$scope.rowClicked (http://localhost:1810/app/controllers/SubjectController.js:12:25)

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong. I used similar code in other places but here it fails each time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "forEach not a function" for this map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096596/why-is-foreach-not-a-function-for-this-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subjects` is an `Object`, not an `Array`, because of its `{}` notation. You can loop through `1` and `100` as keys if you like using `Object.keys(subjects)`. You could also start it out as an empty array (`[]`) and then set the values of `subjects[1]` and `subjects[100]` if you like, but there's no shorthand inline way to just define two separated indices of an array without the inbetween ones.

Comment: More details on the way to Object.keys(objName).forEach(...) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096596/why-is-foreach-not-a-function-for-this-object/31096661

Answer (score 1):

`su.subjects` is an object, not an array and `forEach` is not defined for `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

I would also note that `forEach` is not implemented in all versions of browsers (looking at you, IE 8) since `forEach` was not included until ECMA 5.1. See [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)