# Loop through json and fetch specific values in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, loops

I have a scenario where I am trying to parse through this below json and get all the value of key "name"   and key "id" , which I would further store in a variable or array.

```
  [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvvvv",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app1",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvccc",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app2",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvddd",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app3",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvveee",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app4",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvfff",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app5",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
    }
    ]
```

What I have tried till now( after this not sure how to proceed as this itself provides wrong result)

```
 const dJSON = require('dirty-json');

 const jsn = dJSON.parse(get_all)
 console.log(JSON.stringify(jsn));
 jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsn)
 console.log(jsonData.length) //this returns wrong value

for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++){
    for(key in jsonData[i].entity){
      if(jsonData[i].entity[key] == "name"){
          return console.log(key);
          }
      }
}
```

This doesn't returns the expected output.
Can someone advice here as I am new to nodejs & javascript on how can I extract result like this

expected o/p :

```
{ 
  "app1"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvvvv", 
  "app2"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvccc",
  "app3"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvddd",
  "app4"   :  "vvvvvvvvvveee",
  "app5"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvfff" 
}
```

Comment: will the `metadata` key and `entity` key always be the same

Comment: @Nicolas yes indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) so I can use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the data, I use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the callback passed to map to pull values `metadata.id` and `entity.name` into the scope of the function. I then return a single object with `entity.name` as a key and `metadata.id` as the value. The return value from `map` is a new array, therefore I can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform the array into a different data structure. On each iteration of `reduce` the parameter `current` will be the individual object that was returned out of each iteration of `map`. Because `Object.keys(current)` will always be of length 1 I can use destructuring to pull the only key name out & use key/`name` to populate the return object.

```js
const json = `[
    {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvvvv",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app1",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvccc",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app2",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvddd",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app3",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvveee",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app4",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvfff",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app5",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
  }
  ]`;

const result = JSON.parse(json)
    .map(({ metadata: { id }, entity: { name } }) => {
        return { [name]: id };
    })
    .reduce((prev, current) => {
        const [name] = Object.keys(current);

        prev[name] = current[name];

        return prev;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, could you add a little bit more information about your answer ? Providing just code does not help.

Comment: your code returns this result 
`{ app1: undefined,
  app2: undefined,
  'app3': undefined,
  app4: undefined,
  app5: undefined }`

Comment: @Thomas are you sure, the code snippet is working fine.

Comment: @Nicolas please see explanation

Comment: @DanStarns Yup , I just checked it returns but like this
`{
  app1   :  'vvvvvvvvvvvvv', 
  app2   :  'vvvvvvvvvvccc',
  'app3'   :  'vvvvvvvvvvddd',
  app4   :  'vvvvvvvvvveee',
  app5   :  'vvvvvvvvvvfff 
}`
however you can notice that for `app3` it returns with quotes ('app3') but others it doesnt .. why ?

Comment: @Thomas have you executed the code snippet attached to the answer?

Comment: @Thomas I cant understand your comment, it doesn't matter if an object key is surrounded in quotes this is valid javascript. You can clearly see there is no code specifying that `app3` should be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @Thomas you need to update your question with the JSON that has the quotes. Double check your JSON, because its there in your data and not in your question.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to stackoverflow !
You only need to loop through your Json once, and then get the `metadata.id` and the `entity.name` of each element :

```js
let json = [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvvvv",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app1",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvccc",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app2",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvddd",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app3",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvveee",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app4",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
      },
        {
        "metadata": {
          "id": "vvvvvvvvvvfff",
          "url": "cccccccccccccc",
          "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
          "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
        },
        "entity": {
          "name": "app5",
          "b_enabled": false,
          "d_url": "xxxxxs"
        }
    }
    ]
    
  
    let output = {};
    
    // we parse each element of the json array
    for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i ++ ) {
      // we get the current element.
      let currentElement = json[i];
      // here, we are using the name of the entity as the key and the id of the metadata as the value
      output[currentElement.entity.name] = currentElement.metadata.id;
    }
    
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to iterate over your array. You can use the current iteration item to fill another object, like you've requested in your question.

So first you can create a object to store the filtered results in:

`output = {}`

Next, you can iterate over the array and fill your output object:

`your_array.forEach(item => {output[item.entity.name] = item.metadata.id})`

This will fill up the `output` object with the key-value pairs.

So what it exactly does, is that for each `item` in `your_array`, it will execute the (lambda) function `{output[item.entity.name] = item.metadata.id}`, where `item` is the current iteration item.

---

Total code:

```
var output = {};
your_array.forEach(item => {output[item.entity.name] = item.metadata.id});

// output will now be: 
//  { 
//    "app1"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvvvv", 
//    "app2"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvccc",
//    "app3"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvddd",
//    "app4"   :  "vvvvvvvvvveee",
//    "app5"   :  "vvvvvvvvvvfff" 
//  }
```

Comment: It gives following error `Error: TypeError: jsonData.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @thomas, That is because your `jsonData` is a string, not an array (because you used `JSON.stringify` earlier. Use your variable `jsn` instead of `jsonData`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=[
    {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvvvv",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app1",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvccc",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app2",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvddd",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app3",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvveee",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app4",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
    },
      {
      "metadata": {
        "id": "vvvvvvvvvvfff",
        "url": "cccccccccccccc",
        "created_at": "2019-09-06T08:40:41Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-06T13:25:46Z"
      },
      "entity": {
        "name": "app5",
        "b_enabled": false,
        "d_url": "xxxxxs"
      }
  }
  ]
  
  var myMap =new Map();
 
  arr.forEach((element,index)=>{
    var a= arr[index]
    var id='';
    var name='';
    
   var c= Object.keys(a).map(item=>{
     // console.log(item)
       if(item=="metadata"){
       id=a[item]["id"]
       
       }
      else{
         name=a[item]["name"]
         
         }
        }
   )
  myMap[name]=id;
      
     
  })
  console.log(myMap)
```

Well not the best and optimized solution (i am too new to js) but this solves your problem statement. I am just trying to get the each element of an array which is object and then within each object trying to get the keys of the individual and storing it in variable and then pushing it to the map for desired output. P.s. use you input as arr.
[image]

Comment: Did you run your code snippet? It produces an error.

Comment: in visual studio it is showing the output. Let me debug it

Comment: You haven't included the JSON in the example code snippet. You might want to update your code snippet or remove it since it doesn't work.

Comment: @AyushiKeshri i am not sure but when i try this , it gives me `Error: TypeError: arr.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @Thomas it is working code in vsc , codepen and here .So might be you are doing something wrong.Also common mistake the input is array if you are taking it an object then object dont have for each loop in that case refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096596/why-is-foreach-not-a-function-for-this-object/31096661

Answer (score -1):

In output

key = entity.name

val = metadata.id

of each doc

The approach is simple. Intilize an empty object. Put key, val in empty object.

```
var result = {}
jsonData.forEach(x => {
   result[x.entity.name]= x.metadata.id
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v8w2L1oa/

Comment: Hi, could you add more information about your answer ?

Comment: this returns an array, the question ask for an object to be returned

Comment: @DanStarns Hey, can you check js filddle once. You will get clear answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const jsObj = JSON.parse(json);
  const result = jsObj.map(entry => ({name: entry.entity.name, id: entry.metadata.id}));
  const objResult = {};
  result.forEach(entry => {
    objResult[entry.name] = entry.id;
  });
  console.log(objResult);
```

Output:

```
{ app1: 'vvvvvvvvvvvvv',
  app2: 'vvvvvvvvvvccc',
  app3: 'vvvvvvvvvvddd',
  app4: 'vvvvvvvvvveee',
  app5: 'vvvvvvvvvvfff' }
```

Comment: Hi, could you add more information about your answer ?